# Variável não esta recebendo valor - C#

Tags: c#, variáveis

Por favor, preciso de ajuda,

Tenho três variáveis inteiras, sendo que uma recebe o resultado da divisão das outras duas, porém a receptora não esta recebendo o valor, alguém saberia o por quê?
As duas variáveis envolvidas no calculo estão tendo seus valores setados normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde `atual` está declarada? Neste seu código, a execução para no `while`, portanto `atual` não é performada. Poste o trecho do código onde ela é declarada e onde é alterada.

Answer (score 1):

Ao fazer a operação de divisão `int` / `int`, a linguagem arredonda para baixo para manter o valor como tipo `int`.

`Contador` é 49, `maximum` é > 49.

Uma divisão de um int por um valor maior que ele sempre será menor que `0`, logo, o resultado será arredondado para `0`.

Considere alterar o tipo das variáveis ou use um `cast` para `double` e refaça o teste. :)

Answer (score 0):

Creio que por ser uma divisão entre inteiros o resultado de (contador / maximum) será sempre zero para qualquer valor de contador menor que maximum.
Tente converter esta operação para real ou multiplicar contador por 100 antes de dividir por maximum.